# Can gut be used transitively?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

> It **gutted** him to see her suffer like that.

Can *gut* be used transitively like this?

Or should I rephrase my sentence like this?

> It **left him gutted** to see her suffer like that.

I looked up the word but my dictionary doesn't seem to permit the above usage of **gut.**

Lexico carries a separate entry under **gutted** (adjective) meaning *Bitterly disappointed or upset* but the transitive verb use of the word doesn't seem to be correct.

Why is that?

Comment: @fev- sorry, not quite.

Comment: IMO 'gutted' does come from 'gut'. "It tore my heart out" – "It gutted me" (transitive).

Comment: *He's gutted* is like *He's elated* (and loads more such verbs that I can't think of right now). It's syntactically "valid" to say *[The unfavourable situation] **gutted me***, but idiomatically we usually avoid that form. And *The favourable situation **elated me*** is [an even less likely form.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elated+me%2CI+was+elated&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celated%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20elated%3B%2Cc0) I suggest you avoid the figurative + transitive combination with ***to gut***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica— Thank you very much!

Comment: But Merriam-Webster does give this usage example of the verb _elate_ : *The discovery has elated researchers.* So it's not quite incorrect to use *elate* like this, hmm?

Comment: Yes - it's "not quite incorrect". Like I said, it's "**syntactically valid**", and there *can* be contexts where the usage wouldn't bother native speakers. But as I also said - I'd strongly advise non-native speakers ***not*** to copy this form, because in most contexts ***it won't sound good to the natives***. And trying to identify and communicate all the factors relevant to when you ***can*** reasonably use it is probably not practical.

Comment: Passive *to be let in on [some secret]* is far less idiomatic than transitive *[somebody] **let** [somebody else] **in on** [the secret]*, but you should forget "correct / incorrect" and think in terms of whether a usage is ***likely, idiomatic*** or not. As Winston Churchill is reputed to have said when criticised for ending a sentence with a preposition: *This is the type of errant pedantry up with which I will not put*. I don't know or care whether that Churchillian text or your *The issue was let in on me by them* are "syntactically valid". All that matters is ***we don't say that**!*